# yii2 GridView + PJAX + custom Button for ActionColumn

Tags: ajax, gridview, yii2, pjax

OK I am trying to solve this for many hours now ... quite difficult

So here is the problem combination:
GridView + PJAX  + custom Button for ActionColumn

**What it does correctly:**

- Requests Pjax on click
- Sets active flag via ajax
- Loads the
  new content

**What it does NOT do:**

- keep the URL - aka AFTER the ajax call the URL in the links has changed to "person/active/123" instead of the original "person/index" ....

This is highly problematic since if a user now searches or orders the columns the actionActive will be triggered again.

**My ideas:**

- Set enablePushState = false
  Does not solve the main issue - URL in Browser window is now correct BUT url links in GridView are still "person/active/123"
- Override Yii::$app->request-url on AJAX call

=> No effect

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;
// VIEW 
[
'class'         => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
'template'      => '{active}&nbsp;{view}&nbsp;{update}&nbsp;{delete}',      
'buttons'       => [
   "active" => function ($url, $model) {
        if ($model->active == 1) $icon = "pause";
        else $icon = "play";

        return Html::a(\kartik\helpers\Html::icon($icon), $url, [
        'title'              => Yii::t('app', 'Toogle Active'),
        'data-pjax'          => '1',
        'data-toggle-active' => $model->id
    ]);
   },
],
'urlCreator'    => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
    return \yii\helpers\Url::to(["person/" . $action, "id" => $model->id]);
},
'viewOptions'   => ['label' => \kartik\helpers\Html::icon("folder-open"), 'title' => Yii::t("app", 'View {modelClass}', ['modelClass' => 'Person']), 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip'],
'updateOptions' => ['title' => Yii::t("app", 'Update {modelClass}', ['modelClass' => 'Person']), 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip'],
'deleteOptions' => ['title' => Yii::t("app", 'Delete {modelClass}', ['modelClass' => 'Person']), 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip'],
],

GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'     => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'         => $searchModel,
    'columns'            => $gridColumns,
    'pjax'               => true,
])

// CONTROLLER
public function actionActive($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($model->active == 0) $model->active = 1;
    else $model->active = 0;

    if (!$model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->session->addFlash("error", "Error saving");
    }
    $model->refresh();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) { // Render the index view
        return $this->actionIndex();
    }
    else return $this->redirect(['person/index']);
}
```

Comment: Added issue to repository:
https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid/issues/355

Comment: this approach doesn't seem to respect filters. After the toggle button is clicked and data reloads, all previous GridView filters are being reset. Any idea how preserve previously entered filter inputs?